# How does FIFA 14 selects a player when manually changing the control?

Tags: fifa-14

I usually suffer when there is a pair of players running toward the ball and one of them is more suitable to get the ball but FIFA chooses the other one... On which criteria does FIFA 14 choose the next selected player?

Comment: I "think" it's closest in the direction the ball is moving. I do know you can adjust how it changes the players to your liking.

Comment: If one of the players is in an offside position, he appears to always run back to play the ball rather than leaving it for the onside player.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the ball possession:

1. Air pass selects the closest player depending on the power of the pass. 
   i.e if you have two players standing in the same line and you play an air pass, long pressing the air pass button plays it to the who is at a farther distance where as normal press and release plays it to the nearer player and the appropriate player gets selected.
   Same goes for short pass and long pass(the ground passes), but here the direction is of more importance.
2. When you don't have ball possession and you're tackling press the player run/modifier key and the direction key where the player you want to select is positioned with respect to the current selected player.